# Mail sends fine but returning 504 error

Tags: email, 504

I noticed all of a sudden that any operation that has to do with sending email on my site returns with 504 server timeout page. Fortunately, the email gets sent but returns a 504 error. I went further to create a php script in the root of my application just to send email
`<?php
try{
    mail('name@email.com', 'Testing Magento mail', 'Hello user. Did you get the mail?');
    echo 'Mail sent';
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}`
but got the same effect of timeout. Mails were going fine prior to today and nothing was changed on the server. What could be wrong?

Comment: How did you configure PHP to send mail?

Comment: `sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I solved the issue. It has to do with the way my `etc/hosts` file was configured. I added this line to it.
`127.0.0.1 myServername myServername.localdomain` and it worked.